# Discord bot dice roll error. Why does my code not reach its expected result?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently having a bit of trouble with my Python Discord Bot. The section of code I am trying to program within my bot is a simple dice roll command, however no matter what I try I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it.

The command I am trying to program is "!roll d(number of sides on dice) (number of dice), which should then return the number of dice rolls specified with the number of sides. For example, someone typing "!roll d20 4" should return something along the lines of "Your dice rolls were: 13, 6, 18, 3". This is currently the code I have so far for this:

```
@client.command()
async def roll(ctx, sides, amount):
    try:
        sides = sides.split("d")
        rolls = []
        for number in range(amount):
            result = random.randint(sides[1])
            rolls.append(result)
        rolls = ", ".join(rolls)
        await ctx.send("Your dice rolls were: " + rolls)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Incorrect format for sides of dice (try something like \"!roll d6 1\").")
```

When I run the program, I recieve no errors, even when trying to move the main section outside of the "try" section I receive no errors but still do not receive the expected result, like such:

```
try:
    sides = sides.split("d")
    check = True
except:
    await ctx.send("Incorrect format for sides of dice (try something like \"!roll d6 1\").")
if check == True:
    blah blah rest of code
```

Comment: The common notation for dice rolls is `3d6` ("three six-sided dice"), I suggest you change your bot command format, as `d6 3` is awkward and uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 4 errors in your code:

1. You said that you receieve no errors, that's because you're using bare `except`. Something as simple as

```
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

would give you the error message. If you want more you could also print traceback to pinpoint the faulty code.

2. `random.randint` takes 2 arguments `start` and `end` and both are `int`.

   Right now you're passing only one and it's not even a `int`.

   `sides[1]` will give you a string even if the string contains a number, but the type is still a string because `.split` returns a list of strings. So for example you called `!roll d3 5` then the `sides` will be a list `["d", "3"]` where `sides[1]` will be a string `"3"`
3. Your `rolls` is going to be a list of integers because `random.randint` returns an `int` and you're using `rolls .append(result)` thus `rolls` will be list of ints.

   So you can't use `", ".join(rolls)` because you would be joining integers to string `", "`

   Instead you need to call `", ".join(str(number) for number in rolls)` or you can convert each append call to string right away.
4. `amount` is going to be passed as string so you can't use `range(amount)` it needs to be `range(int(amount))`

So for the full code:

```
async def roll(ctx, sides, amount):
  try:
    sides = int(sides.split("d")[1])
    rolls_list = []
    for number in range(int(amount)):
       # 1 is the minimum number the dice can have
       rolls_list.append(random.randint(1, sides))
    rolls = ", ".join(str(number) for number in rolls_list)
    await ctx.send("Your dice rolls were: " + rolls)
  except Exception as e:
    # You should catch different exceptions for each problem and then handle them
    # Exception is too broad
    print(e)
    await ctx.send("Incorrect format for sides of dice (try something like \"!roll d6 1\").")
```

You should also check for some input errors like if integers are negative aka `amount`